# How to move a group of images at the same time ? D3/SVG

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have a few buttons (images) with a rectangle behind them. I wish to be able to drag the rectangle and the group of buttons move with it.
Is it possible to add an attribute to these buttons so that when I move a certain rectangle, only shapes/images with a certain attribute move with it ?

Comment: How about grouping the elements in a `svg:g`? https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g